# send image from websocket server .NET to client (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, .net, html, canvas, websocket

I'm currently implementing websocket communication betweeb the server (VB .NET) and the client(web page)

I succeeded in sending text from server to the client and display the text using JavaScript and canvas,

Now I want to send an image from the server to be displayed in the HTML5 canvas,

The websocket server implementation I use is [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck)

any suggestion? I lack binary/bmp knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at the Fleck source, you can send binary data using

```
string imgFilePath = ...
socket.send(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imgFilePath));
```

(where socket will be a member variable you store in the `OnOpen` delegate of the `IWebSocketConnection` passed to your server's `Start` method)

Note that not all browsers support reading binary frames yet.  Recent versions of Chrome support it; I'm not sure if any others do yet.

Comment: Firefox 11 does supports binary opcode as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_11_for_developers

Comment: I think it will work, do you know how to receive it at the client side(JavaScript)? I assume it's to convert the binary to image